# nul terminating a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

c89
    gcc (GCC) 4.6.3

Hello,

I am getting a stack dump on *search = '\0'; I thought it was possible to nul terminate a string.

```
char *ptr_name = "hello@home";
char *search = ptr_name;

search = strchr(ptr_name, '@');
search++;
*search = '\0';
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: You're likely writing to constant data.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html

Comment: `ptr_name` is not a string. It is a pointer to a (read-only) string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char *ptr_name = "hello@home";` creates a string constant and that cannot be modified.

To get the result that you are expecting, you need to allocate memory for `"hello@home"` using an array `char arr_name[] = "hello@home";` - or dynamically using `malloc` during runtime.

Your program should be as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char arr_name[] = "hello@home";
    char *search = arr_name;

    printf("%s \n", arr_name);
    search = strchr(arr_name, '@');
    search++;
    *search = '\0';

    printf("%s \n", arr_name);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
hello@home 
hello@ 
$
```

Answer (score 2):

ptr_name points to a string in read-only area.

Instead try :

```
char ptr_name[] = "hello@home"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not when it's a literal const, you can't.  You could strcpy() it into a stack or heap variable, then you can modify it.